# get text from text field without pressing enter key java

Tags: java, swing

How can I get text from text field without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> with Java?

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
       nom=jTextField1.getText();
       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get text from text field without pressing Enter with Java?

What is the complete requirement?

The user uses <kbd>Enter</kbd> to indicate that they have finished typing, in which case you should use the `ActionListener`.

If you need to do processing every time a character is added or removed then you can add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field.

You will then receive an event every time the text is added or removed. Then you can get the entire text from the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a listener to the text field for example by `addActionListener` and on every listener call you can get the current text field value by `getText()` and process it.

Comment: (1-) The code is already using an ActionListener, which is invoked when the Enter key is pressed.